# using cakePHP with google contacts api

Tags: php, cakephp

So, I am able to implement the sample code that is handed out by google in my application.  Which means I am able to get the authorization needed from my application.  Once I click ALLOW to allow my application to have access to my account and display my contacts etc the redirect back to my application does not work.

for example purposes:

`localhost/intranet/`  -->  Display the "Connect Me" to receive the tokens and allow access to the information.

The redirect after the allow brings me back to:

```
https://localhost/intranet?code=4/ECNNFvZpVf_iUpYdsdfsdfXL5R2GBP.oiG-xuYwCAcduJJVnL49Cc9cH8D7cgI
```

Which my cakePHP application does not recognize.  Is this an application setting I can fix? or where would I look to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the specific redirect uri in the api access of the google api.  `https` and `http` do make a difference.